# Does a state has jurisdiction over a docked or moored boat?

Tags: united-states, law-of-the-sea

In particular, if a boat is docked or moored in California coastline do California laws apply or only federal ones?

Comment: is the boat tied up to a physical dock or mooring? Or anchored in a bay or harbor and not attached to a dock?

Comment: I'm curious for all 3 cases: anchored, moored, docked.

Comment: The result wouldn't necessarily be the same for all laws. For example, California debt collection laws might apply to the debt owed to the marina owner for goods purchased for the boat, but might not apply to the employment rights of a sailor employed to work on the boat.